# Dropped Keys and random repeated keys

Tags: keyboard

I'm having an issue with the keyboard on a new Lenovo Yoga 3 14. I installed Ubuntu 14.10. Periodically, it will repeat a keystroke about 20 times. At other times the keyboard seems frozen and the key presses never show up. I've seen some very old posts about this, most in the 2006/2007 time frame. None of the work arounds help. Anyone come across this, or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that the keyboard errors were evident even within the BIOS settings pages. I couldn't very well test the key repeat there, as there is no place to type things, only select settings, but in scrolling through the menus, I noticed the same keyboard freeze issue. Apparently there is a hardware issue at play. I don't think there is anything Ubuntu can do about this. I sent the machine back to Lenovo.