# Keyboard randomly drops keys and leaves a key pressed

Tags: keyboard

I am new to Linux desktops. I have installed two linux distros and I always have the same problem.

My keyboard (SteelSeries Apex 350) get constant key drops. Is not a hardware problem as I have Windows installed in this computer too and the keyboard works flawlessly. I also have tried to plug it to my laptop and it works too.

I have also tried to switch my keyboard layout but it doesn't help.

The Ubuntu installation is the lastest release, almost completely clean.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dropped Keys and random repeated keys](https://askubuntu.com/questions/603817/dropped-keys-and-random-repeated-keys)

Comment: It is not a hw/bios problem, since everything works fine on win!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! I'm sorry but I'm having a hard time understanding your question. Specifically, can you [edit] to elaborate on what you mean by "I have also tried to switch my keyboard distribution but it does anything."? Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Does a regular $10 USB keyboard have the same problem or only the $150 Apex Steel 350 keyboard with 1ms response time, 16 million colors and 22 macro keys?